# Do citizens want different kind of parks?

Tags: simcity-4

I seem to have read on some forum that citizens prefer diversity when raising desirability. That is, plopping down 50 or so of the same park/playground/plaza will have a lower effect than building different types.

Other than a purely aesthetic point of view, does it matter how you mix your parks? I've been checking this list out: http://www.simcitycentral.net/html/cap-relief-list.html but havent found an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://simcity.wikia.com/wiki/Park, citizens don't want different kinds of parks.

But when I played, the citizens got bored from only one type of park.

So I recommend buying lot types of cheap parks instead of one type of expensive parks.